The "Save this Question" manage functionality is broken on BSE
The "Save this Question" manage functionality is broken. I can't save/manage my favorite questions anymore :(

I am presented with the following snippet of HTML code, instead of the Done button so I cannot Save to organize my saved questions.
                </div>

            <div class="d-flex gs8 gsx s-modal--footer mt16">
                <button class="s-btn s-btn__filled js-save-manage-submit" type="submit">Done</button>
                <button class="flex--item s-btn js-modal-close" type="button">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            <button class="s-modal--close s-btn s-btn__muted js-modal-close js-last-tabbable" type="button" aria-label="Close">
                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="m0 svg-icon iconClearSm" width="14" height="14"  viewBox="0 0 14 14"><path  d="M12 3.41 10.59 2 7 5.59 3.41 2 2 3.41 5.59 7 2 10.59 3.41 12 7 8.41 10.59 12 12 10.59 8.41 7 12 3.41Z"/></svg>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</aside>

I noticed that this "Manage" functionality is broken only on BSE. I checked the other communities and there it works fine. How is that possible? Shouldn't the code be common across all stack exchange communities?


BSE and its meta

I can confirm, broken here on meta as well

Just posting to notify that it has been fixed and we can close this question.
